# Select latest documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

My app records some data in MongoDB collection. There are three types of events: 'event1', 'event2', 'event3'. And this elements adds periodically. 
Event structure example:

```
{ 'Data' : 'a234235', 'Type' : 'event1', 'Timestamp' : 1366006599 }
{ 'Data' : 'b978543', 'Type' : 'event2', 'Timestamp' : 1366006600 }
{ 'Data' : 'c567921', 'Type' : 'event3', 'Timestamp' : 1366006601 }
{ 'Data' : 'd327863', 'Type' : 'event1', 'Timestamp' : 1366007100 }
{ 'Data' : 'e012315', 'Type' : 'event2', 'Timestamp' : 1366007102 }
{ 'Data' : 'f834721', 'Type' : 'event3', 'Timestamp' : 1366007103 }
```

Please help compose right query for get current state of each event in database. I need three elements of different types and maximal timestamp.

Comment: you can always fire three separate simple queries :)

Comment: Аnd what to do if I have 200 types of events? :) Unfortunately, this is not the best solution.

Comment: do you simply want the data for the last document of each event type?

Comment: Yes, I do. I want to see three latest documents.
From my example I want to see: `{ 'Data' : 'd327863', 'Type' : 'event1', 'Timestamp' : 1366007100 }, { 'Data' : 'e012315', 'Type' : 'event2', 'Timestamp' : 1366007102 }, { 'Data' : 'f834721', 'Type' : 'event3', 'Timestamp' : 1366007103 }`

Comment: How about using aggregation ?

db.foo.aggregate([
     {$group :{ 
               _id:{"Type":"$Type"},
               Max_Time:{$max:"$Timestamp"}
    }
  }
 ])

Comment: @SrivatsaN: While your aggregation framework query could return a result in a "single query", it will not be overly efficient if needed to execute frequently or if there are a large number of documents. The aggregation example will effectively process all documents in the collection to find the `$max` values, and execution time will grow with the collection.

Comment: @Stennie, I think $max will not process all documents in the collection, it only does it for the grouped type. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @SrivatsaN: you don't have any `$match` criteria and are grouping by type .. so I don't see how this isn't looking at all documents in the collection ;-)

Comment: Thats correct. I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a separate query for each event.

```
db.yourCollection.find({Type:"event1"}).sort({Timestamp:-1}).limit(1);    
db.yourCollection.find({Type:"event2"}).sort({Timestamp:-1}).limit(1);    
db.yourCollection.find({Type:"event3"}).sort({Timestamp:-1}).limit(1);
```

Note that creating an index on the Timestamp field will likely improve the performance a lot.

See also: http://docs.MongoDB.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/

Comment: Are there other solutions? I would like to do it in a single function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you may have ~200 events (as noted in your comments on the question), I would suggest the most efficient approach would be to create a summary document that records the latest events (by type).  This avoids the needs to do separate queries and should be easy to maintain using a `$set` as new event types are observed.

The summary doc would look like:

```
{
    'Event1' : { 'Data' : 'd327863', 'Timestamp' : 1366007100 },
    'Event2' : { 'Data' : 'e012315', 'Timestamp' : 1366007102 },
    'Event3' : { 'Data' : 'f834721', 'Timestamp' : 1366007103 }
}
```

This [pre-aggregated report](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/) pattern will avoid the need for multiple queries if you often need to find the maximal event by type, and save on (potentially large) space for an index on `Timestamp` which would otherwise be needed to find the latest entry efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following JavaScript to get your work done. The drawback here is that I am assuming your events are constant else you need to change this in the "Type" array field.

You can invoke this while connecting to DB.

```
a=function()
{
    var Type = new Array();
    Type[0]="event1";
    Type[1]="event2";
    Type[2]="event3";
    Type[3]="event4";
    Type[4]="event5";

    for (i=0;i<Type.length;i++)
    {

        var myCursor = db.foo.find({Type:Type[i]}).sort({Timestamp:-1}).limit(1);
        myCursor.forEach(printjson);
    }
}
```

and this is the output I got for my test case.

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.2
connecting to: test

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("516bc991cde2925693705103"),
    "Data" : "d327863",
    "Type" : "event1",
    "Timestamp" : 1366007100
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("516bc991cde2925693705104"),
    "Data" : "e012315",
    "Type" : "event2",
    "Timestamp" : 1366007102
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("516bc992cde2925693705105"),
    "Data" : "f834721",
    "Type" : "event3",
    "Timestamp" : 1366007103
}
bye
```

Also note that, by default it connects to test db. Indexing on Type and Timestamp will help you in performance.